# Processing/Java ArrayList & LinkedList exception

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, processing

I am trying to implement a pathfind system into one of my games, 
So i got following problem.

I got here a nice ArrayList :

```
ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now its empty, later in the Process it fills with PVector entrys  :

```
{5.0,6.0,0},{5.0,7.0,0},{5.0,8.0,0},{5.0,9.0,0}
```

Thats nice isnt it ? But i cant work with it, because i need only the 5.0 out of the `{5.0,6.0,0}` ....

i tried it with `path.get(0)`... there i only get `{5.0,6.0,0}`... so i found something new this here :

`path.get(0)[0];` that didnt worked either... because the expression type needs to be an array but its resolved to an object

So how do i get an single entry out of an index ? :/
How do i get `5.0` out of `{5.0,6.0,0}` ?

Comment: Thats not nice because it doesn't compile and it does not have the result you're telling us it has.

Comment: What do you mean ? :/ if you want i can post all 500 lines of code ... but than no one answers too

Comment: First: `int` can not be used in generics, so there _is no_ `ArrayList<int>()` and then, a ArrayList of `Integer`s would not have the result like `{5.0,6.0,0},{5.0,7.0,0},{5.0,8.0,0},{5.0,9.0,0}`, so please, real code...

Comment: Ok thx :) fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions like these, [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is your best friend.

But remember that `path.get(0)` returns a `PVector`. You can then use [the PVector API](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) to get at its position. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
//add PVectors to path
PVector p = path.get(0);
float x = p.x;
```

Notice that I'm using `<PVector>` generics so that the `ArrayList` knows what types of objects it holds. The `p` variable isn't necessary; I'm just using it to show that `path.get()` returns a `PVector`. You could do it in one line as well:

```
ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
//add PVectors to path
float x = path.get(0).x;
```

Comment: Yeah just saw it, i completly forgot about this method, but thx alot :)

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `ArrayList` of `PVector`s, right? This means, when you `get` from the `ArrayList`, you get an `PVector` back. I do not know PVector, but there is (hopefully) a method in `PVector` to get the first int (`x()` or something).

Comment: Man im so stupid .... sure there is :/ sorry, i completly forgot that... Thx man for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring variables, always parametrize the generic types with the most specific type you will store in it:

```
// Declaration:
List<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();

// Storing:
path.add(new PVector(...));
path.add(new PVector(...));
...

// Reading:
PVector pVector=path.get(n);
pVector.get(...)
```

In this way, when reading items from your list, you will get exactly *the same type of object* you stored.